# How do i input words to linked list?

Tags: c, string, linked-list

I had a doubly linked list capable of holding characters in each node. This is what I do to input characters to each node.

```
printf("Enter string of characters for the list: ");
scanf("%s",s);
for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    Insert(s[i],&Header1);
```

Now i wish to modify the list to store words in each node.The input provided by the user is a sentence. How do i make sure each word(separated by space) gets into a node of the list?

Comment: You need to tell us the type and structure of `Header1`. Surely you will have to modify the `Insert` function (so having that code too would be good), and call `scanf` in a loop.

Comment: Or you can take the input by gets() function (It will take the spaces as well) and then you can store the string in your node (Ofcourse, You will have to change the structure of your Node to take Strings instead of characters)

Comment: what is the code inside Insert you have used .. give some details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ( sscanf( sentence, "%s", &node_value ) == 1 )
{
  //Call to insert into your list goes here
  //Each pass node_value will be the next word
}
```

NOTE: You will have to pass `node_value` by value into your list, otherwise all your values will be the same reference!

Answer (score 1):

```
char *word;
while (NULL != (word = strtok(s, " ."))) {
    Insert(word, &Header1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the node as 
`struct node {` 
`node *prev;`
`char *data;` 
`node *next;`
`}`

and change the `scanf` to '`fgets`. 
**Note:** I have declared data as a `char *`, so you cannot use strncpy. If you want to copy the string(instead of assigning pointer), then you should `malloc` the data.